# PHP Need a function to get closest number out of a object

Tags: php, if-statement, closest

I have the following code

```
function closestdown($array, $number) {

                                  sort($array);
                                    foreach ($array as $a) {
                                        if ($a->stappen <= $number){
                                            return $a;
                                    }}
                                    return end($array); // or return NULL;
                                }
```

and i call it like this:

```
$citylist = $manager->getStedenList();            
$stappeng = $user->user_stappen;    
$lowernumber = closestdown($citylist, $currentcity);
```

but instead of giving me the closest number it returns the first lower number it encounters.

example: if i'd use these numbers

```
$lowernumber = closestdown(1 5 6 99 487 98785, 100);
```

it returns : 1 while it should return 99.

$citylist looks like :

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(Steden)#272 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Bourguette"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["stappen"]=>
    string(2) "13"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(Steden)#268 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Gent"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["stappen"]=>
    string(3) "666"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(Steden)#271 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "garabier(Afrika)"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["stappen"]=>
    string(9) "909814037"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(Steden)#297 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Terneuzen"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["stappen"]=>
    string(10) "2147483647"
  }
}
```

How do i get the closest number to $stappeng  (it contains only 1 value example: '100')

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change something in loop

```
<?php
    function closestdown($array, $number) {
      if(count($array)==1){
        return $array[0];
      }
      sort($array);
        foreach ($array as $a) {
            if ($a > $number){//You can use $a->stappen 
                if(($a-$number)<($number-$previous))
                  return $a;
                else
                  return $previous;
            }else{
              $previous = $a;
            }                                        
        }
        return end($array); // or return NULL;
    }
    echo $lowernumber = closestdown([1, 5, 6, 99, 487, 98785], 100);
?>
```

Check demo : https://eval.in/698262

Comment: Please don't accept the answer it is for `right less than` given id not nearest, fail for `98` will give you `6` , should give `99`

Comment: I updated my answer with my above given consideration.

Answer (score 0):

```
function closestdown($array, $number) {
     sort($array);
     $closest = 1000000000000;
     $return = null;
     foreach ($array as $a) {
          if (abs($a->stappen - $number) < $closest && $a->stappen <= $number){
              $closest = abs($a->stappen - $number);
              $return = $a;
     }}
     return $return ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returned first value.

```
$closest = NULL;
foreach ($array as $a) {
    if ($a->stappen <= $number) {
        $closest = $a;
    }
    else /* if ($a->stappen > $number) */ {
        return $closest;
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this..

```
<?php

$array = array(1,4,5,90,99,102,104);
$number = 100;

echo closestdown($array,$number);

function closestdown($array, $number) {

//sort($array);
$temp = array();
foreach ($array as $a) {

    array_push($temp,abs($a-$number));

}
asort($temp);
return $array[key($temp)];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is not necessary for this problem and only slows down your program. Just keep track of the closest 2 numbers so far - a max of numbers that are smaller than target and a min of numbers that are larger than target:

```
function closest($array, $number) {
    $smaller = -INF;
    $larger = INF;
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if ($a <= $number) {
            $smaller = max($smaller, $a);
        }
        if ($a >= $number) {
            $larger = min($larger, $a);
        }
    }
    return abs($larger - $number) < abs($number - $smaller) ? $larger : $smaller;
}

echo (closest([1,5,6,99,487,98785], 100)); // 99
echo "\n";
echo (closest([1,5,6,99,487,98785], 98)); // 99
```

If the array is already sorted, you can take advantage of that by using binary search: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-closest-number-array/